# Angular Login (Frontend) after register redirect to Laravel (Backend)

Tags: redirect, angular6, response, laravel-5.5

I'm developed login and register using Angular 6 and Laravel 5.5. Frontend developed by using Angular and backend developed by using Laravel. After login i should redirect to backend. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add API link function to your Laravel (backend) to validate your users when loggin in then you can include

```
return redirect('/profile');
```

Comment: @RuwanthaSameera have you able to solve this? What about using JWT where did you store it?